# How to call local variable outside of scope?

Tags: python

I wrote a long code but there are some errors! It would be counterproductive towrite all the code but here is a simple example:

```
def func1():
    a = 10
print(a)
```

That creates the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell6>", line 1, in <module>
    print(a)
NameError: Name 'a' is not defined
```

I need 'a' outside the function, not inside.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You need to `return a` from your function. Read into the scope of functions in the local and global namespaces. `a` is defined inside of your function, not outside, therefore when you call `print(a)` outside of your function without returning `a`, the program has no idea what `a` is.

Comment: Look where `a` is defined, and then look where you're trying to print `a` from. `a` is not in scope when you try to print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def func1():
    a = 10
    return a 

print(func1())
```

or

```
def func1():
    a = 10
    return a 

a = func1()   
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

a is outside of scope. It should be:

```
def func1():
    a = 10
    print(a)
```

and when you call as

```
func1()
```

get `10` as result.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but if you read the last sentence of my post you will know why this answer is not useful for me.